# Split text by sentences

Tags: python, regex, python-re, sentence

I run into a problem to find a comfort method to split text by the list of predefined sentences. Sentences can include any special characters and whatever absolutely custom.

Example:

```
text = "My name. is A. His name is B. Her name is C. That's why..."
delims = ["My name. is", "His name is", "Her name is"]
```

I want something like:

```
def custom_sentence_split(text, delims):
     # stuff
     return result

custom_sentence_split(text, delims)
# ["My name. is", "  A. ", "His name is", "  B. ", "Her name is", " C. That's why..."]
```

UPD. Well there can be **non**-comfort solution like that, I'd prefer to getting more comfort one

```
def collect_output(text, finds):
    text_copy = text[:]
    retn = []
    for found in finds:
        part1, part2 = text_copy.split(found, 1)
        retn += [part1, found]
        text_copy = part2
    return retn
    

def custom_sentence_split(text, splitters):
    pattern = "("+"|".join(splitters)+"|)"
    finds = list(filter(bool, re.findall(pattern, text)))
    output = collect_output(text, finds)
    return output
```

UPD2: seems working solution is found.

```
pattern = "("+"|".join(map(re.escape, delims)) +")"; 
re.split(pattern, text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.split) method.

You will need a regex string like `(My\sname\sis|His\sname\sis|Her\sname\sis)`

You could construct your regex string like `"("+"|".join(map(re.escape, delims))+")"`

Edit: You could do something like this:

```
text = "My name is A. His name is B. Her name is C. That's why..."
delims = ["My name is", "His name is", "Her name is"]

import re

def custom_sentence_split(text,delims):
    pattern = "("+"|".join(map(re.escape, delims))+")"
    return re.split(pattern,text)

print(custom_sentence_split(text,delims))
```

Comment: please provide the valid regex if you think this will work, that can be ok as well if I provide 5-10 every-time different sentences, not just a suggestion

Comment: I have added what I believe to be the correct RegEx expression for your example delims, and provided a code snippet with which to generate it (untested). if you are new to RegEx, then https://regex101.com/ is brilliant for debugging RegEx strings

Comment: I found some way to use but still would look for something __more clever__
```pattern = "("+"|".join(delims)+"|)"
   finds = list(filter(bool, re.findall(pattern, text)));
   def collect_output(text, finds):
 text_copy = text[:]
 retn = []
 for found in finds:
  part1, part2 = text_copy.split(found, 1)
  retn += [part1, found]
  text_copy = part2
 return retn
  collect_output(text, finds)
```
Your answer itself is not working - it finds entries correctly but returns a mess instead of non-mathed words. Ok if I wont find something simplier, I'll use my example then

Comment: ````text = "My name is A. His name is B. Her name is C. That's why..."
delims = ["My name is", "His name is", "Her name is"]

import re

def custom_sentence_split(text,delims):
    pattern = "(" + "|".join(delims)+")"
    return re.split(pattern,text)

print(custom_sentence_split(text,delims))```` This seems to work fine -> it creates a list very similar to the expected in your question, with the addition of a blank string at the start, which could be easily filtered out. Edited original answer to preserve formatting

Comment: problem might persist if entire sentence in delims has `.` inside it it does not work then
```
text = "My name. is A. His name is B. Her name is C. That's why..." 
delims = ['My name. is', 'His name is', 'Her name is']
pattern = "("+"|".join(delims)+"|)"
re.split(pattern,text)
# ['', 'My name. is', '', '', ' ', '', 'A', '', '.', '', ' ', 'His name is', '', '', ' ', '', 'B', '', '.', '', ' ', 'Her name is', '', '', ' ', '', 'C', '', '.', '', ' ', '', 'T', '', 'h', '', 'a', '', 't', '', "'", '', 's', '', ' ', '', 'w', '', 'h', '', 'y', '', '.', '', '.', '', '.', '', '']
```

Comment: ````"("+"|".join(delims).replace(" ","\\s").replace(".","\\.")+")"```` to escape the "."

Comment: I dont need to escape any character, search entries can be any kind of text without any adjusting to a characters, it will be pointless thing otherwice

Comment: in regex, certain characters are reserved, for example, ".", which matches any character. to make the regex match a ".", it needs to be escaped with a "\"

Comment: this is invalid because delims can contain whatever symbols and I cannot replace them all.

Comment: @Vova: Why not run them through `re.escape`: `map(re.escape, delims)`?

Comment: @Timus hm seems to be working, I am checking more. `pattern = "("+"|".join(map(re.escape, delims)) +")"; re.split(pattern, text)`

Comment: version with re.escape works I can accept it if you modify

Comment: edited -> that map function is neat

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "My name is A. His name is B. Her name is C. That's why..."

print([x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(.+?[A-Z]\.)', text) if x])

['My name is A.', 'His name is B.', 'Her name is C.', "That's why..."]
```